# Couchbase - Value Eviction to Full Eviction change for huge data base

Tags: spring-data, couchbase

We are having production servers with high volume of data with Value Eviction Buckets. Since we are running out of memory we have decided to change the eviction mode to Full Eviction. If we do this

1. Is there any impact for live operations ?
2. Is there any process running ? (Ex: like re balancing)
3. What are the pros and cons ?

Comment: Are you running Couchbase Server 3.x or 4.x? There are some architectural differences between the two which impact the effectiveness and reliability of Value and Full eviction.

Comment: I am using Couchbase Server 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes there are. There are not many, but that operation requires the memcached processes to be restarted on all nodes at the same time and warm up the caches. So you will incur downtime of course. How much depends on a few factors.
2. Not that I can think of. It just has to restart the processes.
3. Pros: You have more room in RAM as the meta-data is ejected now in addition to values. Cons: If you have it in your code to do any operation that checks for the existence of an object first, it will be much slower. I will give you an example. If you do an upsert, the DB has to check if that object exists first as part of the process. If you are running value eviction, it checks the for the metadata object in RAM which is super quick. That object ID is either there or not. If you are running with full eviction, now Couchbase has to go to disk to look through the meta-data there. As you might imagine, there is a penalty for that, which depending on some factors could be large.

IMO, running out of memory is not a good enough reason to move to full eviction. You need to have a functional reason. Without knowing more information (resident ratios, RAM size, cache sizes, etc. Etc.), you are probably better off adding more servers or larger ones, your choice. Keeping Couchbase properly sized, like most databases, but especially Couchbase is critical to a well functioning system. If you have an Enterprise contract with Couchbase, their Support team can help you with this. If not, read the documentation on this REALLY carefully before you turn on this feature. Like I said, have more than "I am running out of RAM" as the reason you are changing how the DB works, otherwise you may be doing more harm than good.